# Setting the charts using chart.js with the axis points

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, linechart

I am creating a chart using chart.js library, but not able to create the chart as per the exact design. Here is the chart I want to create ---
[image]

here is my code which I created ---

```
var backhaul_his_speed_data_chart = document
  .getElementById("backhaul_his_speed_data_chart")
  .getContext("2d");
var gradient1 = backhaul_his_speed_data_chart.createLinearGradient(
  0,
  0,
  0,
  300
);
gradient1.addColorStop(0, "rgba(84, 224, 255, 0.2)");
gradient1.addColorStop(1, "rgba(84, 224, 255, 0)");
var gradient2 = backhaul_his_speed_data_chart.createLinearGradient(
  0,
  0,
  0,
  300
);
gradient2.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 82, 82, 0.2)");
gradient2.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 82, 82, 0)");
var gradient3 = backhaul_his_speed_data_chart.createLinearGradient(
  0,
  0,
  0,
  300
);
gradient3.addColorStop(0, "rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.2)");
gradient3.addColorStop(1, "rgba(196, 196, 196, 0)");
var gradient4 = backhaul_his_speed_data_chart.createLinearGradient(
  0,
  0,
  0,
  300
);
gradient4.addColorStop(0, "rgba(218, 218, 218, 0.2)");
gradient4.addColorStop(1, "rgba(218, 218, 218, 0)");
var gradient5 = backhaul_his_speed_data_chart.createLinearGradient(
  0,
  0,
  0,
  300
);
gradient5.addColorStop(0, "rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.2)");
gradient5.addColorStop(1, "rgba(238, 238, 238, 0)");
var backhaul_his_speed_data_chart = new Chart(backhaul_his_speed_data_chart, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["Aug 1", "Aug 2", "Aug 3", "Aug 4", "Aug 5", "Aug 6", "Aug 7"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Upload",
        data: [0, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 0],
        pointRadius: 0,
        fill: true,
        borderColor: "#FF5252",
        backgroundColor: gradient2,
        //                    pointBackgroundColor: ['#FB7BDF'],
        borderWidth: 2,
        tension: 0.4
      },
      {
        label: "Download",
        data: [1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2],
        pointRadius: 0,
        fill: true,
        borderColor: "#54E0FF",
        backgroundColor: gradient1,
        //                    pointBackgroundColor: ['#FB7BDF'],
        borderWidth: 2,
        tension: 0.4
      },
      {
        label: "Latency",
        data: [4, 6, 4.2, 4.8, 5, 5.8, 4],
        pointRadius: 0,
        fill: true,
        borderColor: "#C4C4C4",
        backgroundColor: gradient3,
        //                    pointBackgroundColor: ['#FB7BDF'],
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
        label: "Jitter",
        data: [6, 5.7, 8, 6.4, 7.3, 6, 6.2],
        pointRadius: 0,
        fill: true,
        borderColor: "#DADADA",
        backgroundColor: gradient4,
        //                    pointBackgroundColor: ['#FB7BDF'],
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
        label: "Packet Loss",
        data: [7, 6.5, 8.8, 8, 8.2, 8.8, 7],
        pointRadius: 0,
        fill: true,
        borderColor: "#EEEEEE",
        backgroundColor: gradient5,
        //                    pointBackgroundColor: ['#FB7BDF'],
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "bottom",
      labels: {
        boxWidth: 15,
        generateLabels: function (chart) {
          labels = Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);
          labels[0].fillStyle = "#FF5252";
          labels[1].fillStyle = "#54E0FF";
          labels[2].fillStyle = "#C4C4C4";
          labels[3].fillStyle = "#DADADA";
          labels[4].fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
          return labels;
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            offsetGridLines: true
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          display: true,
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            stepSize: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },

    responsive: true
  }
});
```

[image]

it looks like in the screenshot, which is not exact as given in the design, So need to make the designs with the following points --
**1. x-axis point label must be at center with alignment of the label text**
**2. start the plotting from beginning**

please help this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you adjust [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/s4cj6nde/)? It does not look same as your screenshot... you gotta have some other styles involved.

Comment: Amazing skobaljic ! you are right, I am not sure what style added there, is there any chance to get conflict if I am using amchart with charts ?

Comment: It can be anything, you can open your browser inspector and remove styles one by one. If you think it may be amchart, than just remove that script to check it.